# Unable to set subscribe data of BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, subscription, behaviorsubject

Trying with BehaviorSubject and 2 components. But not able to set the data receiving from subscribe.

**Components A**

```
name:string = 'Test';
  constructor( private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(val => this.name = val);
  }
```

**Component B** (with text field)

```
name:string = 'Test';
  frm:FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setup();
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(val => this.name = val);
  }
  setup(){
    this.frm = this.fb.group({
      name:['']
    });
  }
  setData(){
    this.data.changeMessage(this.frm.get('name').value);
  }
```

on form submit setData() function is called.

**Data Service**

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
```

**On load:**

[image]

**On Submit form:**

[image]

Value is changing in Component B but not in A. Whats wrong in A that its not changing? Please Help.

Comment: when are you calling setData method?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate this issue?

Comment: Mm thtat code look good. Can you try put debugger inside subscribe?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckgnsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

> Your service is not a **singleton** service. You have to provided it
>   at the module level or at the root level to make it a **shared**
>   service or a **singleton** service.
>
> Providing service at the component level will create a new instance
>   which is available only to that component.

You can provide the **service** at the root level in the following way or from the **providers** array within the **module** file.

data.service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Also remove providers array from component A and B files, since we are providing at the root level

Comp A

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-a',
  templateUrl: './comp-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-a.component.css'],
  // providers: [DataService]
})
```

Comp B

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-b',
  templateUrl: './comp-b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-b.component.css'],
  // providers: [DataService]
})
```

[Forked Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyi9qw?file=src/comp/data.service.ts)